# How to calculate Pong ball's expected position perfectly (taking wall bounces into account)

Tags: extrapolation

I'm writing a Pong clone where the player has to type a word in order to move the paddle. Because of this, I need a way to calculate the position of the ball immediately after it hits the CPU's paddle. For each letter the player types correctly, the paddle will move a little bit so that when the player finishes the word, the paddle is waiting for the ball to come. It needs to be very accurate, and relatively fast.

I was considering just simulating a much faster ball and figuring out where it will end up (the time it arrives is not important, but the position is). I'm worried that I'll run into problems down the line when the game speed starts ratcheting up, and the actual ball is going as fast as the simulated one. This normally wouldn't be an issue, but the way the whole typing thing works kinda relies on it.

The tough part of just using an equation to find the ball's position is the existence of walls. An equation would be preferable to a quick simulation/extrapolation but I fail to see how it would be done.

Thanks so much for any insight.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use raycasting.

- Cast a ray in the direction the ball will be going.
- If it hits any kind of obstacle, then reflect this vector along the hitpoint's normal.
- Cast a new ray int he reflected direction .
- Repeat until the ball hits the "goal zone".

In the end the last hitpoint's coordinates give where you paddle should be.

This should be quite straightforward if you have a physics engine, also reliable and flexible(until you start to add moving objects, then you'll probably need a faster simulation as you said)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve integrity between user success by typing and pong mechanic you need to 'cheat' a little. Otherwise you will encounter problems when under corner cases(quite literally) ball will be predicted incorrectly.

The concept is:

1)Make the ball own the object defining the Path and its properties like current speed per simulation step.

2)Then use math to simulate several steps ahead considering each paddle is in perfect position to reflect incoming projectile(there are pong games where position of paddle defines angle of ball reflection but I doubt this feature being to be good where player doesn't directly control the paddle)

3)Each simulation step move ball through the path and when it reaches reflection point check if paddle is able to reflect the ball or not. If yes - make it continue path(you can acknowledge reflection with sound to make it more evident) and if not - make it fall beyond the paddle and mark the game to be loosed by party failed to reflect.

This will give a fine control on when AI should fail and where to expect the ball far ahead in time for player.

For specific algorithms of raytracing and reflection consider checking StackOverflow.
Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030565/line-and-line-segment-intersection

Answer (score 0):

I would run the game simulation in a tight loop with fixed timestep, adding the changes to a linked list as I go, until the ball reaches the "point of no return".

Not only do you now know where the paddle should be to bounce the ball correctly, but you can also tell exactly how long the player has to type the word so you can pick a word of suitable length to make the games difficulty curve correct (instead of accidentally giving "Machiavellian" when the ball will bounce right back to the paddle in a second).

As the game carries on you simply use the linked list to pull out the next spot the ball will be in instead of calculating it, that way you are 100% accurate in your prediction since you run the simulation only once.

You will probably have no difficulty whatsoever running the entire path without giving a visual glitch in the game since most pong levels aren't too big, but if you have any issues then simply calculate the path for the next word while the game is displaying the current words action, either in a background thread or by limiting the amount of time spent in your tight loop so it never drops below 60fps.

```
void update() {
  timeS = time();
  while (time() - timeS < 1000/60 && !simulationComplete()) {
    simulatedTime += timestep;
    ball.pos += ball.velocity;
    brick = ball.performCollision();
    actions.add(simulatedTime, ball.position);
    if (brick != null) {
      actions.add(simulatedTime, brick);
    }
  }
}
```